# C# windows form - How do I show href link in text box?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.oneyourall.com/check?.intl=us&amp;p=CL_T4mizBUXf3q00lD.zoTBn3le714BKZaEe7Ln9Ubn10INhhMKvQVwjPu5CQiyEoJU3ebo6uxTh0SUlOD3F0sqqjAxl5co0RnDS84hNmDhm&amp;.partner=&amp;done=">this link</a>
```

I need to display a HREF link in my textbox2.Text section.

How do I show the link in textbox2.Text?

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = Regex.Match(aTagHtmlString, "href=\"([^\"]*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Explanation:

- `href="` you're looking for something that starts with that
- `(...)` you want to capture as a whole anything between the parenthesis
- `[^"]*` capture everything until reaching a `"` symbol, indicating the end of the href attribute value
- `\"` escape the `"` symbol, so the C# compiler doesn't interpret it as the ending of the string

The `href` variable will have the value of the href attribute extracted from the html string.

Comment: Totally I am not understand how I am putting this in textbox2.text? can you explain some more please?

Comment: `textbox2.Text = href;`

Comment: the name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context

the name 'aTaghtmlString' does not exist in the current context. both this error I am getting in the error log why?

Comment: the name 'aTaghtmlString' does not exist in the current context.this error I am getting in the error log why?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what Yorye Nathan has said here is the easiest way is to declare a variable (href in his stated example). then use the textbox[number].text = (variable).

if you dont understand regex id suggest looking it up as it is a very powerful tool but until you get that you could just make your variable a weblink.

another way id use is to use a label or button then use the process to start a browser and navigate to your link - should look something like this:

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender,
LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
Process.Start("http://www.asp.net");
}
```

Edit:

Also forgot to add that in Yorye's example you don't have to use regex but can instead use the "\" to escape certain characters. Though this can make your code a lot more complex and bulky than need be.